# Can't get realgud to work with pdb

Tags: python, realgud

So I have opened a buffer where a python script is loaded.
I do `M-x load-library RET` and after that `realgud:pdb`. Then I get `pdb /path_to_script/main_func.py` which is ok. After pressing enter I get the error `(file-error "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "pdb")`

So how do I get around this. From what I understand and have seen so far pdb is not a standalone executable. It's a module that is imported into the code directly. But from what I can get [here](https://github.com/realgud/realgud/wiki) there are no further steps required to run it (no import as well?). So what am I missing?

I'm on OS X and emacs 25.2 (9)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of possibilities. First, you could create a pdb shell script that invokes pdb. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
python -m pdb $@
```

Or when you are asked `Run pdb like this (pdb ...)` enter, well, the command you want to run, e.g. `python -m pdb ...`

If someone wants to beef up the realgud code to special-case the python debugger (and IMHO too much of Python and the Python ecosystem is its own special case which leads to confusion like this), I'll accept a pull request.

Also, I've added this info off of the link cited.

Comment: Add to .emacs: `(setq realgud:pdb-command-name "python -m pdb")`

Answer (score 0):

Probably `pdb` command is messed up with the password database package.

I use `ipdb` which just works. You have to `pip install ipdb` first. And then do `M-x realgud:ipdb`.